# Is the default copy constructor thread-safe in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, copy-constructor

```
class CSample{
     int a;
     // ..... lots of fields
}
Csample c;
```

As we know, Csample has a default copy constructor. When I do this:

```
Csample d = c
```

the default copy constructor will happen. My question is: is it thread safe? Because maybe someone modifies `c` in another thread when you do the copy constructor. If so, how does the compiler do it? And if not, I think it's horrible that the complier can't guarantee that the copy constructor be thread safe.

Comment: by default, everything are thread-unsafe unless it explicit said otherwise

Comment: Why should the language make all code pay for the cost of thread safety, even code that does not require it? If you expect the language to do that then you need to get a better mental model of the design motivations of the language.

Comment: @BryanChen I disagree with the terminology.  Everything in the standard is "thread safe", since the standard specifies exactly what is required to use the objects in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: You can't access an object in one thread while it is, or may be, modified in another, unless appropriate synchronization is used. You have no synchronization, so that rule applies. The copy constructor accesses `c`, so you can't call it in any context where `c` might be modified.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Usual definitions are that function is "thread safe" if calling it on the same object concurrently is _well defined_ and "reentrant" if calling it concurrently on different objects is well defined. Therefore most things are reentrant, but _not_ thread safe, because calling about anything concurrently on the same object is a data race, which is UndefinedBehaviour™.

Comment: @JanHudec It's an often used definition, but it's also a useless one, since it tells you nothing important.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I agree it does not tell you much if it is true, because you need to know _what_ the semantics is.

Comment: On a side note, it is recommended to _not_ prefix your classes with `C`. Treat it as Microsoft idiosyncrasy that actually helps you avoid conflicts with MFC classes if you don't use that prefix. Yes, Microsoft used `C` for "class", but because almost everything is a class, that is not a useful information to carry around. What _is_ useful is that since you know all their classes have the prefix you can easily avoid conflict by not using it yourself.

Answer (score 15):

**Nothing** in C++ is thread-safe¹ **unless explicitly noted**.

If you need to read object `c` while it may be modified in another thread, you are responsible for locking it. That is a general rule and there is no reason why reading it for purpose of creating a copy should be an exception.

Note, that the copy being created does not need to be locked, because no other thread knows about it yet. Only the source needs to be.

The compiler does not guarantee anything to be thread-safe on it's own, because 99.9% of things *don't need to be thread-safe*. Most things only need to be reentrant³. So in the rare case you actually need to make something thread-safe, you have to use locks ([`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)) or atomic types ([`std::atomic<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)).

You can also simply make your objects constant and then you can read them without locking, because nothing is writing them after creation. Code using constant objects is both more easily parallelised and more easily understood in general, because there is fewer things with state you have to track.

Note that on the most common architecture the `mov` instruction with `int` operands *happens to be* thread-safe. On other CPU types even that might not be true. And because the compiler is allowed to preload values, integer assignment in C++ is **not** anyway.

---

¹<sub>A set of operations is considered thread-safe if calling them concurrently on *the same* object is well defined². In C++, calling any modifying operation and any other operation concurrently on the same object is a data race, which is UndefinedBehaviour™.</sub>

²<sub>It is important to note, that if an object is "thread-safe", it does not really help you much most of the time anyway. Because if an object guarantees that when it's concurrently written you'll always read the new or the old value (C++ allows that when an `int c` is being changed from `0` to `1000` by one thread, another thread may read, say, `232`), most of the time that won't help you, because you need to read multiple values in a consistent state, for which you have to lock over them yourself anyway.</sub>

³<sub>Reentrant means that the same operation may be called on *different* objects at the same time. There are a few functions in standard C library that are *not* reentrant, because they use global (static) buffers or other state. Most have reentrant variants (with `_r` suffix, usually) and the standrd C++ library uses these, so the C++ part is generally reentrant.</sub>

Comment: Given the definition you propose in note 1, your first statement is false: non-mutating accesses are thread safe.  (But your definition in note 1 is interesting: an _object_ is not thread-safe or not; a set of operations is thread-safe.)

Answer (score 5):

The general rule in the standard is simple: if an object (and
sub-objects are objects) is accessed by more than one thread,
*and* is modified by any thread, then all accesses must be
synchronized.  There are numerous reasons for this, but the most
basic one is that **protecting at the lowest level is usually the
wrong level of granularity**; adding synchronization primitives
would only make the code run significantly slower, without any
real advantage for the user, even in a multithreaded
environment.  Even if the copy constructor were "thread-safe",
unless the object is somehow totally independent of all other
context, you'll probably need some sort of synchronization
primitives at a higher level.

And with regards to "thread-safety": the usual meaning among
experienced practitionners it that the object/class/whatever
specifies exactly how much protection it guarantees.  Precisely
because such low level definitions such as you (and many, many
others) seem to use are useless.  Synchronizing each function in
a class is generally useless.  (Java made the experiment, and
then backed off, because the gurantees they made in the initial
versions of their containers turned out to be expensive and
worthless.)

Comment: A "thread-safety" means how much protection the class guarantees. A "thred-safe" class is one that provides defined behaviour in all cases. C++ usually doesn't.

Comment: (And yes, I agree that providing thread-safe classes at low level is useless, because only the high-level code knows which things it needs to lock together.)

Comment: @JanHudec I know, I'm fighting a loosing battle against everyday use of the term.  But we need a term to distinguish between objects which provide some specified level of thread safety, and those which simply cannot be used in a multi-threaded environment at all.  The _standard_ thread safety guarantee (both C++ and Posix) is that you can access in multiple threads if there is no mutation in any thread, but if there is mutation in any thread, all accesses must be protected.  This _is_ a thread safety guarantee (part of the contract), and is more than no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `d` or `c` are accessed concurrently on multiple threads, this is not thread-safe. This would amount to a data-race which is undefined behavior.

```
Csample d = c;
```

is just as unsafe as

```
int d = c;
```

is.

Comment: So that's that complier can't guaruantee the copy constructor thread safe . It's difficult for coders working on multi-threads.It seems that only writing a copy constructor can work.

Comment: @buzz your own copy constructor wouldn't be any safer. Don't ignore the 2nd example of mine. It is just as unsafe. You need a threading tutorial for C++. The rules are more complicated that you might expect.

Comment: @buzz: The compiler **shouldn't** guarantee reading the object for purpose of copying is thread-safe, because in most cases it is not needed.